# Convert large number of data from XML Files to Database

Tags: mysql, xml, xpath

There is a subsystem that generates XML Data File for every Appraisal Request. This XML File may have data for about 1000 fields. There are at least 10000 XML Data Files generated every month. The files are generated on the file server and structured using file system folders. See sample in the snapshot below:

[image]

The structure of XML from one file to another might be different, because the Data Entry specs change over time.

Not all fields need to go to the Database, only certain fields, and at least about 200 fields need to go to Database, in a certain Table. For example, the XML has data say for Contact Details, and Comparable Details. So, for Appraisal Request Number 123, we will insert one record for contacts info in one the contacts table, and one record for comparables info in the comparables table.

**Question**: Is there a way to connect from MySQL or SQL Server to read the XML Files over the file system directly? Is there some intermediate subsystem or connector that makes this process possible. Then, after accessing the XML File, can it be converted to a table format and use normal query to extract the fields and their values?

Currently, we are developing programs in ASP.NET and Java to access the file system, query the XML Data Files (using file system APIs), process each file one at a time, convert the XML Data File to XML Document, use XPath to get the fields and the values, and connect to the Database based on certain mapping (to decide where the XML Element will be save, ie, in which Database/Table/Column) and generate the Insert SQL and execute it to insert the record in the designated table.

[image]

**I am just wondering if there is easier method?**

Answer (score 1):

Using Saxon you could do this in a single XSLT script:

(a) with the `collection()` function you can access all the XML files in the directory and apply the same processing to each one

(b) with Saxon's `sql:insert` extension you can write new rows into the relational database.

This will certainly be a lot less coding than the way you are doing it, though the performance might not be very different (depending on how good your Java code is).

If you invest in Saxon-EE you might get a performance advantage because the collection() function is automatically multi-threaded, so it will take advantage of multiple cores.

[Disclaimer: Saxon is developed by my company]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Please provide link and let me know if there is a demo. I'd like to get more details to suggest it to the team.